# How can I get the size of a zoomed or pinched image in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I had a image which is added to a scrollView, I want to get the size of the image when ever I pinch/zoom that image. Can anyone please help me

Thanks

Praveena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an easier way to get the size –

```
CGSize currentImageSize = myImageView.frame.size;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIScrollView's `zoomScale` property to do that:

```
CGSize imageSize = myImageView.image.size;
int zoomedImageWidth = imageSize.width * scrollView.zoomScale;
int zoomedImageHeight = imageSize.height * scrollView.zoomScale;
```

Comment: wouldn't `CGSize imageSize = myImageView.frame.size;` be better?

Comment: I haven't tried this but it seems to be a simpler solution, yes. You should add this as another answer.